# How do I export my project on AppDrag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, content-management-system

I have used the AWS hosting of AppDrag for my client's project, but he now wants to take it to his own hosting service.  Is there a way to export the site like in a zipped folder so I can send it to him?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  From the AppDrag Dashboard, you open the code editor, where you will find the folders of your site.  Right click the root folder and you should see the download as zip option.